# GNU assembler on Windows: WriteFile returns ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Until now, I've always written Assembly-code in GAS Syntax on Linux, so I wanted to try out how it'd be on Windows. The first goal was to print a single character onto stdout - which didn't work

Here's my code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.extern GetStdHandle
.extern GetLastError
.extern WriteFile
.extern ExitProcess

.section .rodata
        .Lchar: .ascii "F"

.section .data
    .Lbytes_written: .long 0

.section .text

.global main

main:
        mov rcx, -11 //-11 = stdout
        call GetStdHandle
        mov rcx,  rax
        lea rdx, [rip + .Lchar]
        mov  r8, 1
        lea r9, [rip + .Lbytes_written]
        push 0
        call WriteFile
        call GetLastError //After this call, rax=0x6

        xor rcx, rcx
        call ExitProcess
```

After compiling it using `gcc -g -o example.exe ./example.S` (I use mingw64), nothing is printed. When stepping through the code with a debugger, I noticed that GetStdHandle doesn't fail (calling GetLastError directly after it returned 0), but WriteFile fails with 0x6, which is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

So my question is: What could be the issue here? This question is probably very stupid to some, so I apologize in advance.
Thank you!

**Edit**: This has gotten weirder than I thought. Take these two blocks of code

```
.section .rodata
.Lchar: .ascii "F"

.section .data
.Lbytes_written: .long 0

.section .text

.global main

main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax
    lea rdx, [rip + .Lchar]
    mov r8, 1
    lea r9, [rip + .Lbytes_written]
    push 0
    push 0
    call WriteFile
    call GetLastError
    add rsp, 16
    add rsp, 8
    ret
```

```
.section .rodata
.Lchar: .ascii "F"

.section .data
.Lbytes_written: .long 0

.section .text

.global main

main:
    sub rsp, 24
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax
    lea rdx, [rip + .Lchar]
    mov r8, 1
    lea r9, [rip + .Lbytes_written]
    push 0
    push 0
    call WriteFile
    call GetLastError
    add rsp, 16
    add rsp, 24
    ret
```

The only difference is that the second code block allocates 16B more on the Stack, which shouldn't be a problem, as all calls are still 16B-aligned. Yet for the second code block, the call to *WriteFile* does not work. Funnily enough, both function calls to *GetStdHandle* succeed and return the same value (which is 84 in my case)
What could be the source of that?

Comment: `mov rcx,  rax` must be instead  `mov rax,  rcx`

Comment: @RbMm: Really?  Doesn't `GetStdHandle` return in RAX, so you should copy that return value to the first arg of the next call (RCX)?  Maybe you're thinking of AT&T syntax with `mov %src, %dst`, but this is GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` with `mov dst, src`, i.e. normal Intel syntax, mostly MASM-like.

Comment: You didn't align the stack before calling GetStdHandle; I guess it's just luck that it doesn't segfault; unlikely it would fail in some other way.  One `push` after entry to main does re-align the stack by 16 before `WriteFile`.  But don't move that `push 0` earlier; if you did, it would be part of the shadow space for GetStdHandle, so it might not still be 0 when you call WriteFile.  (This is why you have to call ExitProcess instead of `ret` from `main`, because you called functions with main's return address as part of the shadow space they can step on.)

Comment: *Slams head on table* I find it quite funny that while trying to get used to Window's ABI, I missed the one important thing that both have in common
Thank you, it works now! :D

Comment: [GetStdHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) takes a dword input.  Maybe it wants it zero-extended to 64-bit, not sign-extended?  In which case `mov ecx, -11`.  The documentation does seem clear that it's a DWORD, and x86-64 calling conventions normally require the callee to ignore high garbage in the high 32 bits of a register when the arg has a narrower type.

Comment: Oh really, missing stack alignment before `GetStdHandle` made it return a non-working value?  Interesting.  Feel free to post an answer yourself, especially if there's anything interesting to say about how its internals depend on alignment in a way that makes it not segfault but also not happen to work anyway.  (The canonical Q&A about 16-byte stack alignment on x86-64 SysV has many linked questions, probably some about Windows x64, if you want to look for duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/49391001?lq=1)

Comment: @PeterCordes - but i look for `mov  r8, 1` instruction. if assume your interpretation - this is mov r8 to 1  ? so based ot this, i sure that `mov rcx,  rax` must be. ( move rax to rcx) otherwise - must be `mov 1, r8`,

Comment: @RbMm: No, like I said, this is Intel syntax, `mov r8, 1` sets the contents of R8 = 0x0000000000000001,`mov dst, src`, not storing a register to memory at absolute address 1.  `mov rcx, rax` is correct to copy the return value of the first call to the first arg for the 2nd call.  (RCX = RAX, same `mov dst, src`).  It matches `mov r8, 1` in terms of operand-order / direction, not opposite like you seem to be arguing.

Comment: @PeterCordes - dont know. i say that `mov rcx, rax` must be (move value of rax to rcx).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731851/gnu-assembler-on-windows-writefile-returns-error-invalid-handle?noredirect=1#comment125042068_70731851 - my initial comment, which impossible edit after 5 min. i and say - *mov rcx,  rax must be*, and *mov rax,  rcx* is wrong (before question was edited - this was in code)

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, now I understand.  You meant to write: "`mov rcx,  rax` must be *used* instead *of* `mov rax,  rcx`", which has the opposite meaning from the valid English sentence you actually wrote.  (More normal phrasing for that would would be "x must instead be y", but your way was sensible enough I didn't consider any other meaning.)  I didn't see that there was an earlier version of the question that had that instruction backwards.

Comment: @PeterCordes - yes, sorry. i mistake in english as usual. error invalid handle mean that or file handle (rcx) or event handle (from overlapped) is invalid. but here 0 in place pointer to overlapped. so i assume src of error in wron rcx value and in initial code was wrong

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, your comment obviously made enough sense to the author of the question when it appeared under the original code that had the bug, it just didn't age well.

Comment: Yes my question had that mistake in its first version - sorry for the confusion there.
Speaking of edits: I just added a follow-up question, since implementing this minimal example in a larger block of code led to the same issue - nothing happening with error code 0x6. It seems to have something to do with the stack, but I can't figure out what the issue is. In all my "test cases" the Stack was 16B aligned for every call, yet pushing/popping more registers changed the behavior of WriteFile..
@PeterCordes do you have an idea why that could be the case?

Comment: @Tobi: It maybe wasn't stack alignment that was the problem; `push 0` / `call` leaves the arg in the shadow space, not where the function is actually going to look.  (See [comments on Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731851/gnu-assembler-on-windows-writefile-returns-error-invalid-handle/70734980?noredirect=1#comment125048407_70734980).)  So the 5th arg to `WriteFile` is main's return address, in your code.

Comment: the *lpOverlapped* pointer must be at `[rsp + 20h]` before `call WriteFile`. so you need `mov [rsp+20h], 0` instead `push 0` if you want pass 0 here. as result *lpOverlapped* point to random memory. and `hEvent` inside it not 0. but not valid handle. when kernel try convert this trash value to handle - you and got `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it! Thank you for your patience, you guys just saved me a few days of debugging
TIL: I should really read the Windows API more carefully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue with my code was that I violated Windows' ABI, which included

- not aligning the stack properly before a function call
- not adding a 32B padding (shadow space) onto the stack, meaning that the 5th parameter was incorrectly provided

Here's a working version of this code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

.extern GetStdHandle
.extern GetLastError
.extern WriteFile

.section .rodata
.Lchar: .ascii "F"

.section .data
.Lbytes_written: .long 0      # surprisingly just needs to be a dword, not qword in win64

.section .text

.global main

main:
    sub   rsp, 40                      # allocate shadow space + re-align the stack to RSP%16 == 0
    mov   rcx, -11                     # Magic number for stdout
    call  GetStdHandle
    mov   rcx, rax                     # hFile = return value
    lea   rdx, [rip + .Lchar]          # lpBuffer
    mov   r8, 1                        # 1 byte to write
    lea   r9, [rip + .Lbytes_written]  # output arg pointer
    mov   QWORD PTR [rsp + 32], 0      # lpOverlapped=NULL  in the stack space that was padding for the first call
    call  WriteFile
    add   rsp, 40
    ret
```

---

Thank you to Peter Cordes, Joshua and RbMm for helping me on this one!

Comment: Yeah I finally noticed the `push 0` was wrong early this morning and look you fixed it.

Comment: You are missing exception unwind codes. For this simple function, you just need a `PROC FRAME` at the start, and `.allocstack 40` and `.endprolog` after the `sub rsp, 40`. Failing to declare unwind codes will cause your function to be treated as a lightweight leaf function where the return address is always at top-of-stack. Since it isn't, a random stack value will be treated as the return address, causing stack walking to fail and your program to be declared as corrupted (possibly maliciously).

Comment: @RaymondChen
Are you sure that this isn't MASM-only?
Assembling this using gnu as gives me the following output:
```
test.S: Assembler messages:
test.S:18: Error: no such instruction: 'proc FRAME'
test.S:19: Error: unknown pseudo-op: '.allocstack'
test.S:21: Error: unknown pseudo-op: '.endprolog'
```

Comment: Yes, the unwind code pseudo-ops I gave are for masm. I don't know what the gas equivalents are. I found the [ARM unwind pseudo-ops](https://doc.ecoscentric.com/gnutools/doc/as/ARM-Unwinding-Tutorial.html) but couldn't find the x86-64 pseudo-ops (not that I looked very hard).

Answer (score 1):

```
main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle
```

Memory trashed at this point.  The top four slots (32 bytes) in the stack need to be free. The correct line seems to be

```
    sub rsp, 40
```

Moving right along:

```
    call WriteFile
    call GetLastError
```

Mistake here. Check `rax` for error code. If no error, `GetLastError` returns the previous error whatever it was.

If something seems absolutely nuts, check code further along. As far as I can determine from trying to make this stuff work, Windows disassembles your code in some places and code that isn't reached can still crash if it would misalign the stack. I had a case where the crash was due to the difference between not commenting code and commenting code that was unconditionally jumped around.

Comment: This code calls `ExitProcess`, so it's ok to trash `main`'s return address by leaving it as part of the shadow space.  (I mentioned that in a comment on the question, because it's a bug for any more complicated use-case, or for pushing `0` early to align the stack and get the stack arg stored).  If you want to avoid that trashing stuff on the stack, yes, `sub rsp, 40`, or `push 0` / `sub rsp, 32` so `0` as a stack arg will be there for the `call WriteFile`.  (`GetStdHandle` can't step on it because it takes no stack args, so it doesn't own that space.)

Comment: Your last paragraph seems very surprising.  I don't use Windows except casually, but I've never heard of anything like later code (especially unreachable) having an impact on stuff that currently runs in assembly / machine code.  You're sure your debugger wasn't getting mixed up and letting execution continue when you wanted to single-step an asm instruction?  Do you have a citation for Windows disassembling code at the return address and looking into the future about how it would affect the stack pointer?

Comment: @PeterCordes: When I pulled the x64 ABI manual it said those can get trashed even if the function doesn't take enough arguments. It's referred to as register spill space.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Check for exception unwind.

Comment: Stack args go *above* the shadow space, not in.  Yes, all 32 bytes of the shadow space (above RSP when `call` runs) are owned by the callee, regardless of function signature.  But the `push 0` writes the 8 bytes above that, the way I suggested using it.  `push 0` / `sub rsp, 32`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You do realize I'm talking about the call to `GetStdHandle` right?

Comment: I don't know exactly what problem you think you've identified in my suggestion, because I'm still sure there aren't any.  `sub rsp, 40` / `mov qword [rsp+32], 0` / set up regs / `call GetStdHandle` can modify the space from `[rsp + 0..31]` but not `[rsp + 32..39]` because that's above the shadow space, and is not a stack arg *for `GetStdHandle`*; it only takes 3.  Writing that space with a `push` before sub 32 instead of with mov after sub 40 is exactly identical.  The later call to `WriteFile` *could* modify that `0`, because callees own their stack args, and it takes 5 total, so 1 stack.

Comment: Ah, exception unwind could make sense, especially if it's looking for metadata to describe how the stack pointer has moved since function entry, or that the function uses RBP as a traditional frame pointer.  (Especially if it doesn't find such metadata).  I can't work through the details in my head, but I think the mechanism isn't really disassembly, it's parsing separate metadata.  Or does it really try to disassemble if there's no metadata?  What about loops or conditional branches that might skip a push / pop?

Comment: "Or does it really try to disassemble if there's no metadata?" That's almost certainly it. "What about loops or conditional branches that might skip a push / pop?" Here's where my knowledge fails. On one hand I've got something that says don't do this. On the other hand I can't imagine how else C99 flexible arrays compile. But I'm absolutely certain all four slots are reserved even for functions that take fewer arguments and the compiler takes advantage of this to generate tail calls where it otherwise couldn't.

Comment: *But I'm absolutely certain all four slots are reserved even for functions that take fewer arguments* - So am I!  If you think I'm arguing for something different, go look again at the code in my previous comments.  I'm saying stack space *above* those 4 slots is safe, unless the function takes 5 or more args.

Comment: @PeterCordes: At this point I've reached the conclusion that each of us thinks the other one is saying something different than what we're saying.

Comment: In your answer, `sub rsp, 40` is correct and works, as long as you replace the question's `push 0` with `mov qword [rsp+32], 0`.  I also missed that bug in the question when looking earlier: stack args start above the shadow space, where push/call.  (This design makes it possible to dump the 4 register args to form a contiguous array of all args, for easy implementation of variadic functions that index their args by number.)  The optimization I'm suggesting is to replace that later `mov`-0 with an earlier `push 0` and reduce the `sub rsp` to 32, so it still ends up at the same place.

Comment: Re: C99 VLAs: those are scoped to a block, so in C a loop with a VLA destructs it at the end of each allocation.  But `alloca` can be called in a loop.  The normal implementation mechanism is to use RBP as a frame pointer for that function so an arbitrary amount of space can be deallocated with `mov rsp, rbp` (after reloading call-preserved regs with mov relative to RBP, or lea / pop), and implement `alloca` as subtracting an amount from RSP that's rounded up to a multiple of 16, with the return value being the new RSP.  (Which gets assigned to whatever you then do with the return value.)

Comment: @Joshua For the Windows x86-64 ABI, metadata can describe the case where the instruction pointer uniquely determines the offset between the current stack pointer and the initial stack pointer. If the stack pointer does not satisfy this criterion (e.g. `push` in a loop, `alloca()` or VLA), you must use a frame pointer and declare in metadata the offset between the frame pointer and the initial stack pointer. The only time the system tries to disassemble is if it is trying to unwind the prologue or epilogue. Those portions of a function are constrained in what instructions they may execute.